# iterate through a JSON object in react using map

Tags: reactjs

I have this JSON object file

```
const PRODUCTS = {
    "867850": {
        id: "867850",
        category: "Clothes",
        filename: "purse",
        name: "Purse",
        price: 45.48,
    },
```

and I'm trying to iterate through it, so I could display it on my center component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as bs from "react-bootstrap";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
import PRODUCTS from "./products";

function Center(props) {
  return (
    <bs.Container fluid ClassName="p-0">
      <bs.Row noGutters style={{ padding: "6rem 0" }}>
        <bs.Col>{PRODUCTS.map((item, i) => (key = { i }))}</bs.Col>
      </bs.Row>
    </bs.Container>
  );
}

export default Center;
```

I'm getting the error of key not being defined.

Comment: const [key,setKey] = useState(0)
                    {PRODUCTS.map((item,i) => 
                        (setKey(key+i)))}//updates key

Answer (score 0):

Since product is not an array you cannot use map function.

You can try this

```
{Object.values(PRODUCTS).map((item,i) => 
                        (key ={i} ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write code like this-

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import Products from './products'
 const New = (props) =>{
    
    return(
        <div>
       {Products.map((Product, i)=>(
         Object.values(Product).map((prod, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <p>id: {prod.id}</p>
                <p>category: {prod.category}</p>
                <p>filename: {prod.filename}</p>
                <p>name: {prod.name}</p>
                <p>price: {prod.price}</p>
            </div>
          )) 
       )

       )}
        </div>
    );
}
export default New;
```

Comment: And Product file will look like this because it may have many products.   ===>
 const Products =  [ {
    "867850": {
        "id": "867850",
        "category": "Clothes",
        "filename": "purse",
        "name": "Purse",
        "price": 45.48
    }}];

    export default Products;